# Embedding a Drupal block in a Civi dashlet

Tags: drupal, dashlet

Has anyone tried (or better, succeeded) to embed a Drupal block in a Civi dashlet? If so, how?

I'm thinking specifically about that provided by the Masquerade module. It is currently in the sidebar of a Drupal page that is otherwise no longer used, but looks a bit small to have a page of its own. As masquerade is frequently used by our staff it would be nice to have the easy access to this from the Civi dashboard. I could write a Civi page/form that replicates the block, but I'd like to keep the autocomplete it provides and not reinvent the wheel.